# IVY Build, how do I use an extlib directory in the project?

Tags: java, ant, build, ivy

There are several jar files, which are from a COTS product that we keep in our project's "extlib" folder at the root of the project.  I want to have these included in ivy, but not put in the repository, just read from the project/extlib folder.  Is this possible or do I need to add them to the artifactory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an ivy settings file with the following content:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver='artifactory' />
  <resolvers>
    <ibiblio name='artifactory' m2compatible='true' root="http://my.artifactory.server"/>
    <filesystem name='local'>
      <artifact pattern='${ivy.settings.dir}/extlib/[artifact]' />
    </filesystem>
  </resolvers>
  <modules>
    <module organisation='NA' resolver='local' />
  </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

And declare your dependencies as follows:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency org='org.apache.tomcat' name='tomcat-api' rev='7.0.21' />
    ..
    ..
    <dependency org='NA' name='myspecial.jar' rev='NA' />
  </dependencies>
```

The special "NA" organisation is configured to pull files from the "extlib" directory. The revision attribute is manadatory but generally meaningless when referring to files stored within the project directory.